# Encrypted PDF using RC4 ignores permissions

Tags: pdf, encryption

I'm facing an issue that I can't explain.

I've made a PDF file and then decided to encrypt it using the old RC4 format.
Once done, I get an "encrypted" file back.

Reading the content of that file shows it has been encrypted, and the permissions are correct, ie:

```
3 0 obj
<<
/Filter /Standard
/V 2
/Length 128
/R 3
/P -3904
/O <F0299DA33B3988E77ECC4A968F58C8DE50BA19D282C3E9C17E95395E8DCAC43E>
/U <A385DE2CD85CA37B5B365C99EEB05FF228BF4E5E4E758A4164004E56FFFA0108>
>>
endobj
```

(-3904 means no permissions at all, [see this for reference](http://www.biopdf.com/guide/pdf_permissions.php)).

But what's odd is that if I open it on various PDF reader, and I access the document via the user password (not the owner password), **I can do what I want** : Print, Copy, Modify mostly, which should be prohibited based on the current permissions in the document.

This olds true for the default Linux PDF viewer and Firefox reader (from my tests), **but Chrome is respecting the permissions**.

Since Chrome is respecting the permissions, it means they are correct (or are they?), but why then other readers don't respect the permissions?

**How can you reproduce it?**

- Take any PDF you want, and go to https://www.sejda.com/encrypt-pdf
- Submit the document
- Set a password and hit "More options"
- Set a different owner password ("Require a password to change permissions")
- Allow nothing (don't check anything)
- Set the encryption to "Medium (RC4 128bits)"
- Hit submit

Open the document, enter the user password (not the owner password), and print the document... tada, you can! **You shouldn't**.

**Update**: The same thing happens with any encryption scheme (RC4, AES). When you have the document open as a user, you can copy and print even if the permissions say otherwise.

Why is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the pdf specification strictly speaking **requires** that a conforming pdf reader respects the permissions, it also makes clear that nothing in the PDF format itself **enforces** this requirement.

E.g. from ISO 32000-1:

[image: from the specification]

Thus, implementing the "feature" of respecting them has no high priority...

Comment: Is there any way a PDF permission would be respected (by changing the PDF version, format (PDF-A, etc) or anything?

Comment: It cannot be enforced by methods defined in the standard. And as PDF/A is essentially a collection of profiled subsets of the regular pdf standard, those won't help either.

Answer (score 1):

Not all PDF software is created equal, this simply appears to be a bug in FireFox while not in Chrome with regard to *respecting* the intent of the document creator by restricting user access.

I went through your instructions with my own PDF and when I open the resulting encrypted document in Acrobat DC, it correctly doesn't allow printing or exporting images.  I can also confirm viewing the document properties that the permissions are set correctly.  That tells me there's nothing wrong with the way the encrypted PDF was created but rather it's a problem with how this PDF viewer is respecting its permissions.

Comment: So it's worse? This means that no permissions are respected at all :o

Comment: Applications are not forced to respect those permissions. Thus, implementing the "feature" of respecting them has no high priority...

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense.. Thanks!